# How to get random images from an array and show name of image in alert without repeat of same image using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing one project in that i have requirement of get images randomly so i want alert of 9 images every time alert should show random image and it should not repeat but in my case  i am getting alert of Repetative image  and instead of 4 times alert I am getting 8 alerts, here i want count_time=4 which i have declared in variable below my jquery code to get random image in each alert without repeat.

```
      <script>
    //alert shoud get only 4 times because count_time is 4
     $("body").on('click','.cell',function(){
        var images_var = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg"];
                 var count_time=4;
                   var test = [];
                    var useNumbers = {};
                    for (i = 1; test.length < count_time; i++) {
                      var rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * count_time) + 1);
                       var random = images_var[Math.floor(Math.random()*images_var.length)];
                      alert(random);
                      if (!useNumbers[rng]) {
                      test.push(rng);
                      useNumbers[rng] = true;

                      }

                    }
});

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my issue after observing carefully and applying conidtions

```
<script>
$("body").on('click','.cell',function(){

     var images_var = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg"];
                 var count_time=4;
                   var test = [];
                   var img_push=[];
                    var useNumbers = {};var random_img={};
                    for (i =1; test.length < count_time; i++) {

                      var rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * count_time));
                      var random = images_var[Math.floor(Math.random()*images_var.length)];

                      if ((!useNumbers[rng]) && (!random_img[random])) {


                      test.push(rng);
                       img_push.push(random);


                      useNumbers[rng] = true;
                       random_img[random] = true;
  alert(random);
                      }

                    }

      });
</script>
```